# My Slim API gives me a 404 error page

Tags: php, slim

I'm making an API for my angular app that will allow me to access my database with Slim. I followed this tutorial http://anjanawijesundara.blogspot.ca/2015/04/crud-application-with-angularjs.html

I have a 'Angularjs' folder. In it, I have my index.html file, my 'api' folder where is this API, my 'app' folder, for the angular app, and a 'assets' folder for the css, img and other js file.

I installed Slim in the 'API' folder with composer (it created a vendor folder) and I have a 'index.php' file next to the vendor folder.

My 'index.php' file (in the api folder) looks like that so far:

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$app = new \Slim\App;

$app->get('/Types', 'getTypes');
$app->get('/Types/:id', 'getTypeById');

$app->run();

function DB_Connection() {  
    $dbhost = "localhost";
    $dbuser = "kevdug_portfolio";
    $dbpass = "*****************";
    $dbname = "portfolio";
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass);  
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    return $dbh;
}

function getTypes() {
    $sql = "select * FROM pt_type";
    try {
        $db = DB_Connection();
        $stmt = $db->query($sql);  
        $list = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        $db = null;
        echo json_encode($list);
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}'; 
    }
}

function getTypeById($id) {
    $sql = "select * FROM pt_type WHERE id=".$id;
    try {
        $db = DB_Connection();
        $stmt = $db->query($sql);  
        $list = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        $db = null;
        echo json_encode($list);
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}'; 
    }
}

?>
```

I'm suppose to be able to use my API with this code:

```
angular.module('appDatabaseCtrl', [])
.controller('databaseCtrl', ['$scope','$routeParams', '$http', '$log',
    function($scope, $routeParams, $http, $log){
        $scope.testDatabaseTypes = function(){
            $http.get('/api/Types').success(function(data) {
                $log.info("succes!");
                $log.log(data);
            })
            .error(function (data, status){
                $log.error("error!");
                $log.log(data);
            });
        };
        $scope.testDatabaseTypesById = function(){
            console.log($scope.id);
            $http.get('/api/Types/' + $scope.id).success(function(data) {
                $log.info("succes!");
                $log.log(data);
            })
            .error(function (data, status){
                $log.error("error!");
                $log.log(data);
            });
        };
    }
]);
```

The first function works, but the second returns me a 404 error. You can see what happen yourself with those tree url:

http://kevdug.webfactional.com/#/database

http://kevdug.webfactional.com/api/types

http://kevdug.webfactional.com/api/types/1  <--- can be any id from 1 to 4

Comment: What about using the function name directly instead of quoting it, i.e. `$app->get('/Types', getTypes);`? Function names as strings are technically callable in PHP but the framework appears to use string route handlers for referencing methods of controller classes

Comment: have you tried by typing the "index.php" on the url?
something like http://localhost:8080/angularjs/api/index.php/Types

Comment: For your comment, mzulch, I really don't know what to answer you because I just don't understand what your saying...  For Pekoso, it does work if I had index.php, but if I tried adding an id to get a specific type, it gives me a 404 error. I updated my question with more detail and 3 link to really see what happen. Hope someone can help!

Comment: You have no route for `/`

Comment: there aren't suppose to be any

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you are using Slim v3 (Judging by `$app = new \Slim\App;`), however it appears that your route format is that of Slim v2.

`$app->get('/Types/:id', 'getTypeById');` should actually be more like `$app->get('/Types/{id}', getTypeById);`. You can also provide restrictions as to what it accepts like `$app->get('/Types/{id:\d+}', getTypeById);`

Edit: You are also using an invalid function signature for Slim v3, which is why when navigating to [Your Example Url with the literal `:id` instead of a number it errors](http://kevdug.webfactional.com/api/types/:id). You should use a function signature like

```
function getTypeById(\Slim\Http\Request $req, \Slim\Http\Response $res, $args) {
    $id = $args["id"]; // Rest of your code
}
```

Finally, i recommend looking up some basic SQL Injection protection tutorials, as because if your current /Types/:id route worked correctly, it would have a SQL Injection Vulnerability. However since that is not the target of this question, i'll just leave a warning.

Comment: Thank you soooooooo much! It works, but I have afew questions for you:
-When I look at the exemple Slim gives on is website, they have to use command at the top (you can check it on there website). Are those necessary and what do they do?
-What do you mean by invalid function signature and must I use $req and $res since I never use those variables in my code?

Comment: If you mean the `use \Namespace\Class;` code at the top of each example, that is so you don't need to use fully qualified names for Type Hinting. As for the function signature, in Slim v3, PSR-7 is implemented and used, which retrieves and outputs data via the Request and Response classes, it's a bit complex to go into in a comment, so you'll need to read up about it elsewhere.

Comment: I tried removing everything that came before $arg in my function, but it gives me an error. Does it means that if I want to use  the $arg, I must of $req and $res before it? Also, Is it o.k. if I replace those two with "Request $request, Response $response" since I have both use statement at the top of my document?

Comment: The purpose of PSR-7 is to control the flow of data more concisely, than the willy-nilly echo's of php, so you should use the $request and $response objects, but yes they are required to access $args. And yes, as long as you have the respective using statements in the current php file, than you can shorten them down to the class name, however they are only required if you want Type Hinting, you can omit them completely. EG: `getTypeById($req, $res, $args)`

Comment: Thanks, you really help me out!